# I'm running a odd/even game in Python and I get stuck once I need to define a winner

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

#Here I define the user and cpu function

```
cpu_num = random.randint(1,6)
user_selection = ["Odd", "Even"]

def cpu_choice():
    choice = random.randint(1,6)
    print("The computer's choice is",choice)
    return choice

def user_choice():
    while(True):
        choice = input("Odd or Even? ")
        if choice in user_selection:
            print("Your choice is",choice)
            return choice
        else:
            print("You did not write your answer correctly, please try again.")
```

#In this function I define the result of each round based on previous formulas and two new variables (num_rounds and user_lives) and everything works well

```
def round_result():
    num_rounds = 0
    user_lives = 10
    while num_rounds < 8 and user_lives > 0:
        user_pick = user_choice()
        cpu_pick = cpu_choice()
        if (cpu_pick % 2 == 0) and (user_pick == "Even"):
                    print (f'You have {user_lives + cpu_pick} lives left')
                    num_rounds += 1
                    user_lives = user_lives + cpu_pick
        if (cpu_pick % 2 == 0) and (user_pick == "Odd"):
                    print (f'You have {user_lives - cpu_pick} lives left')
                    num_rounds += 1
                    user_lives = user_lives - cpu_pick
        if (cpu_pick % 2 != 0) and (user_pick == "Even"):
                    print (f'You have {user_lives - cpu_pick} lives left')
                    num_rounds += 1
                    user_lives = user_lives - cpu_pick
        if (cpu_pick % 2 != 0) and (user_pick == "Odd"):
                    print (f'You have {user_lives + cpu_pick} lives left')
                    num_rounds += 1
                    user_lives = user_lives + cpu_pick
```

#Everything works well until here, I don't know what am I doing wrong in the winner function

```
def winner():
    user_won = user_lives > 0 and num_rounds == 8
    cpu_won = user_lives < 0
    game = round_result()
    while game:
        if user_won is True:
            print ('You won')
        if cpu_won is True:
            print ('Cpu won')
```

Comment: can you give more detail about the error or the unexpected result you are getting?

Comment: You might want to do `while round_result():` as at the moment, once you enter the while loop you never exit it.  You might also want to return or exit the if there is a winner.

Comment: @BSP I would like to create a function that: if user has <0 lives at any round --> CPU wins or if user has >0 lives and num_rounds == 8 --> USER wins

Comment: @JonSG I've tried this code (adding the while round_result(): and the return) and it does not work:
        
 def winner():
    while round_result():
        if user_lives > 0 and num_rounds == 8:
            return print ("You won")
        if user_lives <= 0:
            return print ("You won")